# Save Filter for Taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, taxonomy

I want to get rid of undesired HTML, mostly being published by my editors when copying text from other sources, like other pages or from Word

Therefore I use

```
add_filter( 'content_save_pre' , 'my_function', 10, 1 );
```

for the content in posts.

I want to do the same for the taxonomies/terms and their description, but I didn't find any filter in the WordPress documentation, nor could I find anything in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are e.g. the following dynamic [`sanitize_term_fields()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1506) filters:

- `edit_term_{$field}` filter for the *edit* context
- `pre_term_{$field}` filter for the the *db* context
- `term_{$field}_rss` filter for the the *rss* context
- `term_{$field}` filter (default)

and also the taxonomy-specific ones:

- `edit_{$taxonomy}_{$field}` filter for the *edit* context
- `pre_{$taxonomy}_{$field}` filter for the the *db* context
- `{$taxonomy}_{$field}_rss` filter for the the *rss* context
- `{$taxonomy}_{$field}` filter (default)

If the context is *raw* then none of the above filters are applied.

The *db* context is used within the `wp_insert_term()` and  `wp_update_term()`:

```
$args = sanitize_term($args, $taxonomy, 'db');
```

There's also the `pre_insert_term` filter wihtin `wp_insert_term()`.

```
/**
 * Filters a term before it is sanitized and inserted into the database.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $term     The term to add or update.
 * @param string $taxonomy Taxonomy slug.
 */
 $term = apply_filters( 'pre_insert_term', $term, $taxonomy );
```

Here are simple demo examples for the *term description* in the case of the *post tags* taxonomy:

*edit* context:

```
add_filter( 'edit_post_tag_description', 'wp_strip_all_tags' );
```

*db* context:

```
add_filter( 'pre_post_tag_description', 'wp_strip_all_tags' );
```

You might want to test and restrict this further to your needs.

*Note: It might be better to just strip it where you output the term description on the front-end, so you don't mess with the user input in the backend?*

Comment: That looks pretty much like what I need. Is there a generic one, that fires for all taxonomies? Or do I have to hook into all manually.

Comment: Since both `wp_insert_term()` and `wp_date_term()` use it in the "db" context, you could try that first. Yes we can adjust it for all taxonomies, I will update the answer @ChristophDaum